# Commas getting automatically removed when writing into Gsheet via pygsheets

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, pygsheets

I am trying to write Pandas DF into GSheet via pygsheets library.

```
brand_list = [
["Progressive",["Progressive"],["Progressive","PROGRESSIVE"]],

["USAA",["USAA"],["USAA","Usaa"]],

["State Farm",["State Farm"],["State Farm","STATE FARM"]],

["Geico",["Geico","GEICO","Geico - Renters Insurance","Geico - App"],["Geico","GEICO"]],

["Allstate",["Allstate"],["Allstate","ALLSTATE"]],

["Dell",["Dell"],["DELL","Dell"]],

["Lenovo",["Lenovo"],["LENOVO"]],

["HP",["HP"],["HP"]],

["Apple",["Apple","Apple iPhone","Apple - iPhone 12 Pro","Apple - iPhone","Apple TV+","Apple TV+ - Palmer","Apple - MacBook","Apple TV+ - The Snoopy Show","Apple TV+ - Various","Apple Music","Apple TV+ - Losing Alice","Apple - Apple Watch Series 6","Apple TV+ - Greyhound"],["APPLE"]]]

customSchema = StructType([
  StructField("ParentCompany", StringType(), True),
  StructField("BrandName1", ArrayType(StringType()), True), 
  StructField("BrandName2", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(brand_list,schema=customSchema)
df1_pd = df1.toPandas()
```

This is my sample data set.
Now i am trying to push this df to gsheet via pygsheets.

```
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file = 'xxxxxxxx.json')
google_workbook='Demo Data'
google_sheet='Sheet1'

sheet = gc.open(google_workbook)
wks = sheet.worksheet_by_title(google_sheet)

wks.set_dataframe(df1_pd,(1,1),copy_head=True)
```

But when I am writing the data, the data is getting written into the sheet but the commas between the items in the array are getting missed.Attaching the screenshot of the issue, can anyone help me how to write the values without missing the comma ?

[image]

Comment: check if  `df1_pd.astype('unicode').values.tolist()` has commas.

Comment: yes @Nithin it has commas